# How will webpack come to know about index.html, a file to load bundle.js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have not given any specific command to load index.html but webpack is loading the index.html page whenever i make changes in a file.

webpack.config.js file and package.json files are attached bellow

**webpack.config.js**

```
var config = {
entry: './root.tsx',
output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
},
devServer: {
    inline: true,
    port: 8888
},
node: {
    fs: "empty",
    net: "empty",
    tls: "empty"
},
devtool: "#eval-source-map",
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
            presets: ['es2015', 'react']
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
            {loader: "style-loader"},
            {loader: "css-loader" },
            {loader: "sass-loader"}]
        },
        {
            test: /\.tsx$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'ts-loader',            

        }
    ]
}
}
module.exports = config;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "mypackage",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --watch-poll",
    "test": "mocha --reporter spec testSetup.js \"testCase/*.spec.js\""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.3",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.8",
    "enzyme": "^2.9.1",
    "expect": "^22.0.3",
    "jsdom": "^9.12.0",
    "mocha": "^4.1.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.6.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.2.0",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.19.1",
    "ts-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.0.34",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.3",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.2.3",
    "axios": "^0.17.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "debug": "^3.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "mysql": "^2.15.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-responsive-table": "^2.0.15",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-table": "^6.7.6",
    "sinon": "^4.1.4",
    "typescript": "^2.6.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.7"
  }
}
```

Please someone tell me where the webpack is understanding that, it has to load index.html

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`webpack-dev-server`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server) injects some code into your `bundle.js` file that will triggers a page reload after you make changes to your assets (JS/CSS).  By default it knows to look for an `index.html` file in your root directory. Both [the name of the index file](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-index) and [the directory to look for it in](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-contentbase) are configurable.

You can change the behavior to only compile your assets when you manually refresh the page by setting [`lazy: true`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-lazy-) inside the `devServer` object.  This can be inconvenient because it may take webpack a few seconds to compile your assets after you trigger a refresh.

An alternative is to make the refresh less obtrusive by enabling [hot reloading](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-hot). This won't lose state by fully refreshing the page, but instead will try to replace your live code on the fly with the newly compiled version.

If you want webpack to compile your assets as soon as you change them, but want to manually control page refresh, a third option is to set the config [`watch: True`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/) (at the top level, not in the `devServer` object) and disable the `webpack-dev-server`.  In this case, run a separate simple web server like [`http-server`](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server) in the same directory as your `index.html` to serve you page.

Comment: how to give the path of index.html when its not in the root directory

Comment: You can set the `devServer` [`contentBase`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-contentbase). For example, adding `./dist` causes the dev server to send `./dist/index.html` when you navigate to localhost:8888.  Note that [the documentation recommends using an absolute path](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-contentbase), I'm using a relative path for simplicity.